# Sphinx - combine OR operator with field start/end modifier

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

Is this expression write right? Because I don't received all results as expected:

```
(@nationality_code ("^MD$" | "^GB$" | "^IT$"))
```

I should get all users with the nationality code equal to 'MD' or 'GB' or 'IT'

Should be like this query in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE nationality_code IN ('MD', 'GB', 'IT')
```

**UPDATE**
If I search for only MD and GB, I receive the right results:

The query I execute is this:

```
SELECT id, nationality_code 
FROM jobs_applied_main 
WHERE MATCH('(@nationality_code ("^MD$" | "^GB$"))') AND job_id = '6257' 
LIMIT 0, 999;
```

[image]

But If I add also "^IT$", I don't get users with nationality "MD" anymore.

[image]

If I remove start/end modifier, I receive the results that I'm expected, Why this behavior?

**UPDATE**
So, here my index dump and sphinx.conf file: [sphinx-dump](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b96b58a781482d7668f70b249cadb2c220181001132656/2678a4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with Sphinx 3.0.3 ver, because with Sphinx 2.2.11 it works

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The expression is right. It works fine for me:

```
[snikolaev@dev01 ~]$ mysql -P9314 -h0
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 2.7.1 668faae@180620 dev

Copyright (c) 2009-2017 Percona LLC and/or its affiliates
Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select * from idx_min where match('(@nationality_code ("^MD$" | "^GB$" | "^IT$"))');
+------+------------------+------+
| id   | nationality_code | a    |
+------+------------------+------+
|    1 | MD               |  123 |
|    2 | GB               |  123 |
+------+------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Make sure you really have just MD/GB/IT with nothing before/after that in the index and that you don't have min_word_len < 2.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I had min_word_len < 2. My actual config is like this: `min_word_len            = 1
    min_infix_len           = 2
    min_prefix_len          = 1
    expand_keywords         = 1` So what is the right config?

Comment: @Mintendo Sorry, I meant that you don't have min_word_len > 2 (not < 2). In your case if you have min_word_len = 2 it should work fine. I've just checked again with min_word_len = 2, min_prefix_len = 1 and expand_keywords = 1 - works fine. What's your Sphinx version? Can you provide your full config and run indexation with --dump-rows and provide the file (or part of it)?

Comment: Ok I add an update of my question, can you check above? Anyway, my sphinx version is 3.0.3-dev

Comment: @Mintendo still works for me in 3.0.3. It will be easier if you provide your config and how to reproduce your index (--dump-rows or just the index files)

Comment: Ok, I uploaded sphinx.conf in wetransfer and provided the link above

Comment: Sorry, I forget to upload also the dump, I uploaded a zip file

Comment: @Mintendo I could reproduce your issue and it looks like this is a bug in Sphinx 3. I cannot reproduce the issue in Sphinx 2.2.10 and also in Manticore 2.7.3 it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181092/discussion-between-manticore-sphinx-next-gen-and-mintendo).